How to create such draggable marker for Flutter Map?
I am trying for a days to create flutter_map's custom marker. The main thing is that it should have icon and line connected to some card which will show text from list. Icon will be static it will be on the map, and only card will be draggable/movable and also line will change its size and direction based on card placement (map will run as default and will be draggable/movable).

This is code for above picture
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

// Entry point
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ItemsScene(),
    );
  }
}

// Stateful widget to manage dragging and connecting items
class ItemsScene extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ItemsSceneState createState() => _ItemsSceneState();
}

class _ItemsSceneState extends State<ItemsScene> {
  // Initial position for the location_on icon (fixed)
  LatLng fixedIconPosition = LatLng(51.5, -0.09);
  // Position for the draggable card in screen coordinates
  Offset draggableCardOffset = Offset(300, 300);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        // Flutter Map
        FlutterMap(
          options: MapOptions(
            initialCenter: fixedIconPosition,
            initialZoom: 13.0,
          ),
          children: [
            TileLayer(
              urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
              subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            ),
            MarkerLayer(
              markers: [
                Marker(
                  point: fixedIconPosition,
                  child: Icon(Icons.location_on, size: 48, color: Colors.red),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // Draggable card
        Positioned(
          left: draggableCardOffset.dx,
          top: draggableCardOffset.dy,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              setState(() {
                draggableCardOffset = Offset(
                  draggableCardOffset.dx + details.delta.dx,
                  draggableCardOffset.dy + details.delta.dy,
                );
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text('Draggable Card')),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        CustomPaint(
          painter: CurvedPainter(offsets: [
            Offset(
              (fixedIconPosition.longitude + 180) *
                  (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 360),
              (90 - fixedIconPosition.latitude) *
                  (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 180),
            ),
            draggableCardOffset,
          ]),
        ),
        // Custom painter for drawing the connection line
        // CustomPaint(
        //   painter: CurvedPainter(
        //     offsets: [
        //       Offset(
        //         (fixedIconPosition.longitude + 180) *
        //             (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 360),
        //         (90 - fixedIconPosition.latitude) *
        //             (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 180),
        //       ),
        //       draggableCardOffset,
        //     ],
        //   ),
        //   child: Container(),
        // ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

// Custom painter to draw the connection line
class CurvedPainter extends CustomPainter {
  CurvedPainter({required this.offsets});

  final List<Offset> offsets;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (offsets.length > 1) {
      for (int index = 1; index < offsets.length; index++) {
        canvas.drawLine(
          offsets[index - 1],
          offsets[index],
          Paint()
            ..color = Colors.red
            ..strokeWidth = 2,
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CurvedPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

The goal is below picture.

And the question is, if it is possible and how ? Or is there any premade library for that which will be used as flutter_map's marker, it is like tooltip but draggable across the whole map ?
The reason why I am doing such things is that when I have multiple points on the same street, items are overlapping.
Thanks
I tried my skills of coding, bit googling and stackoverflow (this question).
May be I am asking different thing and want different one ?
I do not know how and what is is called it, I mean the widget type.
